# How to lower the volume of the second audio channel with FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, audio, conversion

It's easy to mute one of the audio channels of a video, but I have to lower the second one with some dB.

I have searched in documentation about mapping the channels but I am still confised how to lower the volume of the specific channel. I have only two audio channels in my videos.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few hours of searching, I was only able to find [this.](https://superuser.com/questions/769168/ffmpeg-mixing-and-setting-each-volume-of-a-multi-audio-track-file)

I don't know if that's kind of what you are looking for, or at least gives you the info you need to modify the channel volume.

I hope it helps!